# Page Map Level 4 Paging

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I established 2 MB Page Map Level 4 paging while moving from real mode to long mode. Now i would like to establish 1 GB Page Map Level 4 paging. To do this,I need code snippet. Can i move from 32-bit mode to long mode. How? Please give me details.